# C docs: help Doxygen recognize class structure

Tags: c, documentation, doxygen

I have a C library for which I would like to auto-generate some API documentation. Doxygen seems to be the *de facto* tool for this type of thing, so I've written a couple toy classes (using the same coding style as my library) to test it out. A couple of notes about the coding style:

- Each class has a header (`.h`) file containing a typedef of the class's data structure and prototypes for all class methods. This is the information I want users of my library to be able to see.
- A corresponding `.c` file contains the full data structure definition as well as the implementation of all the class methods. The details of implementation should not show up in the API docs.
- See https://github.com/standage/doc-test for the toy example code.

When I run Doyxgen on my example, this is what I get: http://standage.github.io/doc-test. The resulting docs are a bit kludgy--there is a list of data structures and a list of files. Ideally, what I would like is a class list, where each class page shows the functions/methods associated with that class, and where class names link to the detail page for that class. Is this possible with Doxygen (or any other tool)?

Comment: Is this C? What is a class in C?

Comment: Well, exactly. C doesn't have any standard syntax for OOP. I'm wondering if there is a way to get Doxygen to recognize the classes as such.

Answer (score 1):

Doxygen supports documentation of "C classes" - just add

1. the `\class` directive to the struct containing its data members
2. the `\memberof` directive to its functions
3. `\public` or `\private` directive to functions/members

Example:

```c
/** This is My Class!
    \class MyClass
    */
typedef struct MyClass
{
 /** This is member A 
   \private
   */
 int memberA;
 /** This is member B 
   \private
   */
 int memberB;

} MyClass;

/** A private member function of MyClass
    \param i Some value
    \private
    \memberof MyClass
    */
static void MyClass_privateFunction(struct MyClass* this, int i)
{
}

/** A public member function of MyClass
    \param j Some other value
    \public
    \memberof MyClass
    */
void MyClass_publicFunction(struct MyClass* this, int j)
{
}
```

If you set Doxygen's `EXTRACT_PRIVATE` to `NO`, only the public part will be documented.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Exclude series of tags in your configuration file.

Since your source is in the ./src/ directory, one option might be to use one of the following:

Exclude a directory:

```
EXCLUDE = /src
```

Exclude a pattern of file names:

```
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS = *.c
```

These are off of the top of my head. You might have to add some path information. I expect that using the first or both will produce output that does not have any of the comments in your C files.

As a side note, do you think using a structure for the interface for your 'class' would meet your requirements?